# ReactJS - how to return a list of html elements in string as html elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React class that produces a string of html elements from a JSON:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Maps.css";
import df3 from "./data/df3.json"
import sample from "./data/sample.json"

class Maps extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const data = df3;
    this.state = data 
}

  render()

  {
    var df4 = df3["ds"]
    var d1 = '';
    for (var key in df4)
    {
       var host = df4[key];
       d1 += '<div class="'+key+'" value="'+host[0]+'"/>';
    }

    return (
      <div id="Maps"><div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the json :

```
{"ds":{
  "s1": {
    "0": 0.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0,
}
  "s1": {
    "0": 0.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0,
}
  "s3": {
    "0": 2.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0,
}}
```

console logging v1 shows us the string (the first value from each object):

```
'<div class="s1" value="0"/><div class="s2" value="0"/><div class="s3" value="2"/>'
```

i would like to convert this string to a set of html elements, and return them

```
return (
      <div id="Maps"> 
        <div class="s1" value="0"/> 
        <div class="s2" value="0"/>
        <div class="s3" value="2"/> 
      </div>
    )
```

any assistance is deeply appreciated : )

Comment: How to render lists is part of the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component)

Comment: you must map on your array and return new jsx element, because now you operate with a simple string, but jsx-element it's not that simple, so see my example:```const list = df4.map(e =><div class={e.class}>{e.value}</div>```. And  then render it ```render(){return list}```

Comment: this gives me "df4.map is not a function"

Comment: That means `df4` isn't an array. Use `Object.entries(df4).map(([key, host]) => ...)`

Answer (score 1):

i created an example for useing map in this sandbox url ->
https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-water-ycy37?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
//.json
    [
     { "class": "s1", "value": "0" },
     { "class": "s2", "value": "1" },
     { "class": "s3", "value": "2" },
     { "class": "s4", "value": "3" }
    ]


import React from "react";
import data from "./data.json";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="Maps">
        {data.map(element => (
          <div className={element.class} key={element.value}>
            {element.value}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: As I said in my comment, you're basically repeating official documentation.

Comment: i get : _data_df3_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.map is not a function

Comment: can you post your df3.json ?

Comment: posted the json (simplified version) : )

Comment: that is not a valid json array

Comment: { "ds": [ {"s1": { "0" : "0.0"} }, {"s2": { "0" : "0.0"} } ] }
use " for key and values, use , between object of array, you could use this site for create valid json https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: went to the site, and produced a new json, but still getting the same error

Comment: i converted your data to valid json, compare those to understand your mistakes
{"ds":[
  {"s1": {
    "0": 0.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0
}},
  {"s1": {
    "0": 0.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0
}},
  {"s3": {
    "0": 2.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0
}}
]}

Answer (score -1):

Use the dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute on a parent html element like:

```
let htmlString = '<div class="s1" value="0"/><div class="s2" value="0"/><div class="s3" value="2"/>'
```

Make sure that variable htmlString is accessible. Then put it in the div or any other element:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString) }}></div>
```

Comment: It would make more sense to render `div` elements in the `render` function like normal. There does not appear to be any benefit to building the HTML by hand.